# How does one interpret this path description in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was looking through some perfectly good working code using `d3.js` and I saw a path described in the `DOM` elements which looks like this:

```
<path d="M764.4,489.99999999999994L772.8000000000001,
480.19999999999993L781.2, ... [snip]"
style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(0, 100, 0); stroke-width: 2px;">
</path>
```

The numbers seem reasonable for pixel positions, but what do the M and L designate?  They seem to serve as commas but clearly they do more than that.

Comment: Check this [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html).

Comment: Thanks @FernOfTheAndes In my mind it I thought it had to be something like that but I couldn't quite figure it out.